# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen día me genera este error cuando intento mandar un viewbag a mi vista y recorrerlo mediante un foreach con razor

Controller:

```
 ViewBag.Eq_tblEquipo_id = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblEquipos, "id", "NoSerie");
```

Vista:

```
  @foreach (var dato in ViewBag.Eq_tblEquipo_id)
        {
            <dd class="col-md-1">
                @dato
            </dd>
        }
```

alguien sabe que error puedo estar cometiendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El  `ViewBag.Eq_tblEquipo_id` o `db.Eq_tblEquipos` te deben estar llegando nulos. Me decantaría más por el `db.`.

Este error sucede cuando tienes un objeto nulo e intentas acceder a una de sus propiedades, es decir, `db` es null pero intentas acceder a `db.Eq_tblEquipos`.

Una forma de resolver este problema es añadiendo el operador de *nullable* escribiendo `db?.Eq_tblEquipos` que significa en caso de que `db` sea nulo en vez de intentar acceder a `Eq_tblEquipos` devolverá directamente el valor *null*.

Comment: si estaban llegando nulos, gracias por tu ayuda